# Constuction of a $ \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ function

Tags: functions, real-numbers

Is it possible to constuct (+ example) a function $P$, such that $P:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. ($\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ being the set of all $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ functions)

Additionally is it possible for $P$ to have the property ,$P(f+g) = P(f) + P(g)$.

Comment: Doesn't $P(f)=f(0)$ work?  Or $P(f)=z$ where $z(x)\equiv 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is, however, the set on the left is far bigger than the one on the left, so be careful, and you lose a lot of information.
However, an example would be any evaluation:
$$P_a:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\\
f \mapsto f(a)$$
this also has your desired property

Comment: would it be possible without loss of information?

Comment: No, the set on the righthandside has a strictly bigger cardinality (it contains the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$), there is NO bijective map between those two sets!

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is $P(f) = f(0)$ for every $f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.